# How to consider different costs for different types of errors in SVM using R

Tags: r, svm

Let Y be a binary variable.

If we use logistic regression for modeling, then we can use `cv.glm` for cross validation and there we can specify the cost function in the `cost` argument. By specifying the cost function, we can assign different unit costs to different types of errors:predicted Yes|reference is No or predicted No|reference is Yes.

I am wondering if I could achieve the same in SVM. In other words, is there a way for me to specify a cost(loss) function instead of using built-in loss function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the Answer by Yueguoguo, there is also three more solutions, the standard Wrapper approach, hyperplane tuning and the one in e1017.

The Wrapper approach (available out of the box for example in weka) is applicable to almost all classifiers. The idea is to over- or undersample the data in accordance with the misclassification costs. The learned model if trained to optimise accuracy is optimal under the costs.

The second idea is frequently used in textminining. The classification is svm's are derived from distance to the hyperplane. For linear separable problems this distance is {1,-1} for the support vectors. The classification of a new example is then basically, whether the distance is positive or negative. However, one can also shift this distance and not make the decision and 0 but move it for example towards 0.8. That way the classifications are shifted in one or the other direction, while the general shape of the data is not altered.

Finally, some machine learning toolkits have a build in parameter for class specific costs like `class.weights` in the `e1017` implementation. the name is due to the fact that the term `cost` is pre-occupied.

Answer (score 0):

The loss function for SVM hyperplane parameters is automatically tuned thanks to the beautiful theoretical foundation of the algorithm. SVM applies cross-validation for tuning hyperparameters. Say, an RBF kernel is used, cross validation is to select the optimal combination of C (cost) and gamma (kernel parameter) for the best performance, measured by certain metrics (e.g., mean squared error). In e1071, the performance can be obtained by using `tune` method, where the range of hyperparameters as well as attribute of cross-validation (i.e., 5-, 10- or more fold cross validation) can be specified.

To obtain comparative cross-validation results by using Area-Under-Curve type of error measurement, one can train different models with different hyperparameter configurations and then validate the model against sets of pre-labelled data.

Hope the answer helps.

Comment: Your answer is correct too compared to the answer that has been accepted. I accept the other one because it gives more options and more detail on the programming detail. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to explain from a theoretical point of view. CAFEBABE's answer is better in terms of practical detail.